# Is a variable or a function?

Tags: swift

I see some code on github.

```
private static var allMemes:[MemeModel]{
        return getMemeStorage().memes
    }
```

Is this a variable or a function or other?
Thanks

Comment: It is a computed property

Comment: That's a static computed property – I would highly recommend reading the [properties section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: Hint: `func` means function. `var` means variable. `let` means constant.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Computed Properties
>
> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and
>   enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually
>   store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter
>   to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.
>
> ```
> struct Point {
>   var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
> }
> struct Size {
>   var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
> }
> struct Rect {
>   var origin = Point()
>   var size = Size()
>   var center: Point {
>     get {
>         let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
>         let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
>         return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
>     }
>     set(newCenter) {
>         origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
>         origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Ref : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html